# Set variable in all JSP pages

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have many page in **.jsp** and i want to specify the context and the **css/js** version in all my page like this :

```
<c:set var="version" value="0.0.1" />
<c:set var="path"    value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${path}/resources/css/foo.css?v=${version}">
```

How to set just one time `path` variable and my custom variable `version` for all my JSP pages ?

Comment: Put it in an included JSP file and set to request scope?

Comment: @DaveNewton and i have to include this file in all my jsp pages ?

Comment: If you want to do it like that, yes. The idea of putting it into session via a filter is a cleaner solution, but it depends on your needs. I'd argue that you've split up your CSS too much, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to be accessible by all jsps even after redirects and etc, you should make them session scoped, therefore they won't "die" after each request and will live as long as user's session lives :

`<c:set var="version" value="0.0.1" scope="session" />
<c:set var="path" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" scope="session" />`

Comment: and where i put this ? in jsp file and i include it in all jsp pages ?

Comment: Yes, but only if this page is executed as the first one, otherwise you might want to implement some [filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html) and set variable there, or do it in the servlet using `request.getSession().setAttribute(String s, Object value);`